# Computing frequency of membership in R's data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data.frame:

```
authors <- data.frame(
    surname = I(c("Tukey", "Venables", "Tierney", "Ripley", "McNeil")),
    nationality = c("US", "Australia", "US", "UK", "Australia"),
    deceased = c("yes", rep("no", 3),"noinfo"))
```

which produce this output:

```
      surname nationality deceased
1    Tukey          US      yes
2 Venables   Australia       no
3  Tierney          US       no
4   Ripley          UK       no
5   McNeil   Australia   noinfo
```

What I want to do is to get the frequency of `deceased` by `nationality`.
Yielding this output:

```
US yes 1
US no  1
US noinfo 0
Australia yes 0
Australia no 1
Australia noinfo 1
UK yes 0
UK no 1
UK noinfo 0
```

At the moment I can only display the statistics through `tables`.

```
stat <- table(authors)
```

I'm not sure how to proceed by accessing the element of the tables.
Advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `table` on the things you want the occurence for...

```
table( authors[ c("nationality" , "deceased" ) ] )
#           deceased
#nationality no noinfo yes
#  Australia  1      1   0
#  UK         1      0   0
#  US         1      0   1
```

And to get the *exact* output you want... turn it into a `data.frame`....

```
data.frame( table( authors[ c("nationality" , "deceased" ) ] ) )
#  nationality deceased Freq
#1   Australia       no    1
#2          UK       no    1
#3          US       no    1
#4   Australia   noinfo    1
#5          UK   noinfo    0
#6          US   noinfo    0
#7   Australia      yes    0
#8          UK      yes    0
#9          US      yes    1
```